# iPhone - backBarButtonItem is nil and does not highlight when touched

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back-button, null

I have a fullscreen modalView called with :

```
PreferencesController *nextWindow = [[[PreferencesController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Preferences" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController* navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextWindow] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Then from this modalView I push another view :

```
MyController *nextWindow = [[[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tmp" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextWindow animated:YES];
```

In this new controller, I have this viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Borders";
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

Doing like this, the backBarButtonItem is not active, I mean touching it does not highlight it nor goes back to the previous view.

In fact, self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem is NIL.
self.navigationController.navigationItem is not NIL
self.navigationController for caller and inside called view have the same reference.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the final solution.
In fact, there is a problem when a new controller is used from a camera overlay to display a new view.
At some moment, the navigationBar does not work.
To make it work fine, you must call the first view not from self (the overlay) but from the ImagePicker itself. So you need to keep a reference to the picker on the overlay :

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

[some initialisation of the picker]

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
-- HERE --self.overlay.pickerRef = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

Then in the overlay :

```
- (IBAction) click:(id)sender {

    PreferencesController *nextWindow = [[[PreferencesController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Preferences" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextWindow] autorelease];

    -- DO --      [self.pickerRef presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    -- DONT DO -- [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Then no more navigation problem...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're **nextWindow** UIViewController has reference to the UINavigationController.

#### Update #1

My current Application is a Tab Bar Application, so when i need to set the navigation controller reference i just let me new incoming View Controller referenced the navigation controller from the base class that controls the tabs.

i am sorry the previous answer i was totally wrong, i hope this would help you.

#### Update #2

Please try this before pushing the UIViewController:

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; 
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; [backButton setTitle:Title forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
UIBarButtonItem *iButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];     
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = iButton;
```

#### Update #3

copy and paste definePreferences method to your project

```
 -(IBAction) definePreferences:(id)sender {

 PreferencesController *nextWindow = [[PreferencesController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Preferences" bundle:nil] ;
 nextWindow.caller = self;
 UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextWindow];
 [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

#### Update #4

- I Added a NavigationBar in the Prefrences 2  Nib file
- Then connected it with IBOutlet of type UINavigationItem in Prefrences 2 UIViewController
- In ViewDidLoad: of Prefrences2 UIViewController: add the following code to ensure there is a left bar item is being added [1]
- Then the function that is going to handle going back[2]

[1]

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[backButton setTitle:@"Helo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem* iButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton]; 

self.oUINavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = iButton;}
```

[2]

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

please let me know if you need me to explain more.

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : nextWindow.navigationController is a readonly property. Can you please delete or modify your answer so further readers won't try it ?

Comment: @@Ahmad Kayyali : See my edit, I've tested that the two navigationControllers are set and are the same. So the problem does not seems to be there

Comment: I want you to test something please, i want to explicitly insert a new Button on the navigationItem left button, UPDATED!

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : I've placed the sample code of my project here : http://shine.free.fr/fgdfgdfgdfgd/Test.zip Can you see what goes wrong ?

Comment: @Oliver it's the autorelese thing, i have tested the application on my iPhone and now it's working.

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : Uhhhh, have you cleaned the project before building and delete any version of the installed app on the iPhone before running ? Because Update 3 doesn't work for me.

Comment: yes i did and i could navigate from the main view to the options and back to the main view which is the cam, i am positive about this! are u sure you removed the autorelease from the initWithNibName?

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : Yes, I'm sure. I've copyed your code and replaced mine. Did you go to the "Options 2" view ? (Main -> Options -> Options 2). Because if you did, I don't understand why this don't work on my phone (iPhone 4, iOS 4.2.1)

Comment: i am really shocked! i am not the office right i will send you back tomorrow morning, my country is +2 GMT that means i will send you back in less than 8 hours :)

Comment: anyway is MAIN -> Options -> Back to main is working? because it was not working too' in the project you sent me.

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : OK, see ya later ;-)    Main -> Options -> Back works. Main -> Options -> Options 2 -> Back don't work. This last one is my problem

Comment: @Oliver: Things Got worked finally man, i am sending you the project, i need you to provide me with with your email.

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : Thank you. I understand what you did and I thought to do it so. But in the project I have made, the app creates a NavigationBar itself that does not respond. So there is a bad code somewhere in my app and I want to correct it. Doing this way only hides it and the problem will appear somewhere else, or can cause unwanted leaks on the users phone. Do you see where is the bug ?

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : Can you precise what you did at the line `self.oUINavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = iButton`. It does not compile if I connect oUINavigationItem to a UINavigationBar.

Comment: you have Two options: 1. Redesign you application to be Navigation Based Application or as i just now  2. modify your project to stop using the navigation-> push controller and use "PresentmodalViewcontroller" and on hiding use "DismissModalViewControllerAnimated" it's your call.

Comment: @Ahmad Kayyali : you seems to be right. I'll use your solution and will continue to search a little bit, because I'm curious :-). Thank you very much for your help ! Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

When you push view controller into navigation controller, it's backBarButtonItem will be set up for back to previous view controller, not leftBarButtonItem. If you set up leftBarButtonItem, the backBarButtonItem will be hide and the same place will be replaced by the leftBarButtonItem.

And your code doesn't set leftBarButtonItem at all, so of course it is nil.

EDIT:
  My test codes. I checked the backButtonItem and leftBarButtonItem by following codes, and they are nil. You are right. But when I touched the back button to previous view, its color did change, so it was highlighted. And it worked well back to previous view controller. So I think your code is wrong at some else place, it makes the back button inactive.

Listing 1, RootViewController class

```
// RootViewController.h 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end

// RootViewController.m
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"RootView";

MyViewController *childView = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:childView] autorelease];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCtrl animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Listing 2, MyViewController

```
// MyViewController.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end

// MyViewController.m
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "MyAnotherViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"MyView";

    NSLog(@"%s backBarButtonItem:%@ leftBarButtonItem:%@",__FUNCTION__ ,self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem, self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem);
    MyAnotherViewController *childView = [[[MyAnotherViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Listing 3, MyAnotherViewController

```
// MyAnotherViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAnotherViewController : UIViewController {
}

@end

// MyAnotherViewController.m
#import "MyAnotherViewController.h"
@implementation MyAnotherViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Another View";
}

@end
```

Comment: OK, my fault :-)  but it's the same with backBarButtonItem : it's nil too

Comment: I checked it and I found you are right. The backBarButtonItem is nil too. :-)

Comment: But the backBarButtonItem is highlighted when I touched. And I found a funny thing that when the title of root view controller is nil, and push a view controller into navigation controller, there is no back button on the navigation bar. But after I assigned a title for root view controller, and push a view controller, I can see the back  button on the bar.

Comment: I've placed the sample project of my problem here : http://shine.free.fr/fgdfgdfgdfgd/Test.zip for test. That's a strange behavious...